# Como preservar o cache de um iframe?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Ao mudar uma rota do angular, gostaria de preservar o cache de um iframe que foi lido e renderizado:

```
$scope.loading_guten_pro = false;

$scope.url_pro = '/acesso-pro';

$scope.iframePro = function() {
    $scope.loading_guten_pro = true;
    var iframe = '<iframe width="800" class="iframe-pro" id="content_iframe_pro" src="'+$scope.url_pro+'" frameborder="0" style="height:92vh" scrolling="auto" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
    $("#iframe_content_pro").html(iframe);
    $('#content_iframe_pro').contents().find('.header').remove();
    $('#content_iframe_pro').on('load',function () {
            $scope.loading_guten_pro = false;
    });
};
$scope.iframePro();
```

Comment: Você quer CACHE mesmo, ou o que você quer é "manter o frame" com o conteudo já carregado, porque CACHE não é resolvido no front-end.

Answer (score 2):

Você quer CACHE mesmo, ou o que você quer é "manter o frame" com o conteudo já carregado? Digo isto **porque CACHE não é resolvido no front-end.**, é resolvido na resposta HTTP junto a interface do navegador.

Se a intenção é manter apenas o iframe então a solução é manipular o DOM

> Vou começar com uma critica construtiva, não entendo qual a intenção de usar jQuery com Angular.js, não que de problemas, mas com certeza é tipo querer dirigir dois carros ao mesmo tempo, mas isto é algo que foge ao escopo da pergunta atual, então em outro momento falarei disto.

Se a intenção é apenas manter o iframe com o conteudo já carregado então pode manipular o DOM assim:

```
var cachedframes = {};

$scope.iframePro = function() {

    var target = document.getElementById('#iframe_content_pro');

    if (!target) return;

    //Checa se já existe o iframe
    if (cachedframes[$scope.url_pro]) {
         target.html(iframe);
         return;
    }

    $scope.loading_guten_pro = true;

    var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');

    iframe.setAttribute('class', 'iframe-pro');
    iframe.setAttribute('style', 'height:92vh');
    iframe.setAttribute('scrolling', 'auto');
    iframe.setAttribute('allowfullscreen', '');

    iframe.addEventListener('load', loaded);

    iframe.src = $scope.url_pro;

    cachediframes[$scope.url_pro] = iframe;

    function loaded() {
         var header = iframe.contentWindow.querySelector('.header');

         if (header.parentNode) header.parentNode.removeChild(header);

         header = null;

         $scope.loading_guten_pro = false;

         iframe.removeEventListener('load', loaded);
    }
};
```

Pronto, desta forma quando trocar as rotas no Angular.js o proprio scope vai alternar os iframes para cada rota, note que removi o ID do iframe, pois IDs repetidos é algo que pode sim dar problema.

Também resolvi tudo com javascript, sem necessidade de jQuery.

Para explicar melhor, todo iframe criado é adicionado ao objeto `cachediframes` e fica lá salvo, tendo sido carregado ou não, esta if checa se já existe o iframe:

```
//Checa se já existe o iframe
if (cachedframes[$scope.url_pro]) {
     target.html(iframe);
     return;
}
```

E o `return;` impede que o script continue ali.

Comment: Eu removi o iframe e taquei o conteúdo direto pra resolver o problema, mas no caso, eu queria manter o conteúdo que já foi renderizado quando muda a rota... pois toda vez que eu mudava ele renderizava a view internamente no iframe.